# Show that a set of continuity points has an open dense subset

Tags: continuity, solution-verification, baire-category

> Let $f_n:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous maps, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, and $f_n(x)\to f(x),\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.
>
> 1. Let $\varepsilon>0$. Show that there there is an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ and a non-empty open ball $B\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ such that $(\forall x\in B)(\forall n\ge N)(|f_n(x)-f(x)|\le \varepsilon)$.
> 2. Let $\varepsilon>0$. Show that $X:=\{x\in \mathbb{R}: (\exists \delta >0)(\forall y\in\mathbb{R})(|x-y|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon\}$ contains an open dense subset.
> 3. Show that the set of all continuity points of $f$ is dense.

My attempt:

- This is a very straightforward application of Baire's Theorem. I've mentioned this result just in case it can come in handy for question 2.
- By question 1. we have $(\exists N\in\mathbb{N})(\forall x\in B)(\forall n\ge N)(|f_n(x)-f(x)|\le \varepsilon/4).$ Let $x,y\in B$ then $|f(x)-f(y)|\le |f(x)-f_N(x)| + |f_N(x)-f_N(y)| + |f_N(y)-f(y)|$. Because $f_N$ is continuous, there exists some $\delta>0$ s.t. $|f(x)-f(y)|\le 3\varepsilon/4 <\varepsilon$ whenever $x,y\in B$ and $|x-y|<\delta$. This problem is giving off strong Baire-vibes (concluding that $\bigcup_n U_n$ is dense), but then again, an arbitrary intersection of open sets is not necessarily open... Any hints?
- We see that $X$ from question 2. is the set of continuity points of $f$. We've shown that there is some open, dense subset $V\subseteq X$. To show that $X$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ it suffices to show that $V$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $U\ne\emptyset$ be open in $\mathbb{R}$, then $U\cap X$ is open in $X$ so that $U\cap X\cap V=U\cap V\ne\emptyset$ *given that* $U\cap X\ne \emptyset$. I'm stuck here. Possibly there's another way out by explicitly constructing $V$ in question 2. and proceeding from there.

Comment: >We see that X from question 2. is the set of continuity points of f
Is it? It' just for some $\varepsilon$, not for any.

Comment: That's a good catch, didn't notice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2. Similarly to 1 (or even as corollary from it) we can show that any interval $(a, b)$ contains a non-empty ball $B_{a, b}$ s.t. $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \varepsilon$ for $x \in B$ and large enough $n$. As you have shown, $B_{a, b} \subset X$.

Now, take union $\bigcup_{a, b \in \mathbb Q} B_{a, b}$ - it's dense (because it intersects any interval), it's open (as union of open sets) and it's subset of $X$.

3. Let $X_\varepsilon$ be open dense subset from $X$ from question 2. Then $\bigcap_n X_\frac{1}{n}$ is intersection of countably many dense open sets - and thus itself open dense by Baire theorem.